# Map subclass to same table as parent class without discriminator

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to map a subclass of an existing entity onto the same table as the parent entity, like so:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
public class Child : Parent
{
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> {get; set;}
}
```

The child entity is identical to the parent except that it contains some navigation properties; the reason the child class exists (instead of adding the navigation properties to the parent class) is that the parent class is closed for modification (different assembly).

Entity framework doesn't like me mapping these to the same database table, expecting a discriminator column.  How can I tell EF that these are really the same entity (just that I want some extra navigation properties on the child)?

Answer (score 0):

Put them on separate `DbContext`'s.  The EF model builder looks for collisions between entities / tables on the properties of it's own context, not others.